# Replacing font sizes in RTE by own font sizes

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

I want to set some font size classes for the user to select in the RTE. I've found, how to add font size classes and how to show the drop-down in the RTE controls:

```
RTE.fontSizes {
    large {
        name = Large
        value = 1.2em
    }
    small {
        name = Small
        value = 0.8em
    }
}
RTE.default.buttons.fontsize.addItems = large, small
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(fontsize)
```

This adds me the two font size classes to a list of default font size classes. How can I replace that list by a list with my two sizes instead of adding them to the default list?

**EDIT**

I'm using Typo3 7.6.

**EDIT II**

I solved it with this code:

```
RTE {
    default {
        contentCSS = typo3conf/ext/mySiteExtension/Resources/Public/Css/shared.css

        buttons.formatblock.addItems = large
        buttons.formatblock.items.large.label = Large
        buttons.formatblock.items.large.addClass = large
        buttons.formatblock.items.large.tagName = h2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution:

```
<p class="large">Some text</p>
```

Add the class in rte:

```
RTE {
default {
    # link to site css 
    stylesheetcontentCSS = fileadmin/Public/css/rte.css

    # clear typical styling
    classesLinks =buttons { 
        blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses := addToList(large)
    }

    # list all available classes here, otherwise they're removed on RTE save
    proc.allowedClasses := addToList(large)
  }
}
```

now, add the class in the rtc.css:

```
p.large{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work for me. But searching for a solution without using the font size list leaded me to a working solution. I'll edit my question again to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below typoscript in Page TSConfig. define fontsize in `rte.css` file

```
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/css/rte.css
```